# How can I trigger ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I've just retrieved JSON data back from my database, in my success callback I update a `$scope.requests` array which should update my DOM. However, nothing happens even though the array's value has changed.

I'm pretty new to Angular so I am probably missing something fairly straight forward:

**Callback code:** (part of FetchUserCtrl)

```
// Success callback from server - returns the data from PHP file
callback.success(function(data) {

        // Build the request array to update DOM
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $scope.requests.push( { name: data[i].name, dob: data[i].dob } );
        }

        $scope.apply(); <-- I read that this should apply changes.
});
```

**HTML**

```
<aside id="previousFeed" ng-controller="FetchUserCtrl">
    <div class="priorResult" ng-repeat="request in requests">
        <p>{{ "hi" }}</p>
    </div>
</aside>
```

What I want to happen, is when the `$scope.requests` array is changed in my success callback, a `div` should be drawn for each object in the `$scope.requests` array.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? Is that `$scope` part of the `FetchUserCtrl`? Are you sure angular is working at all? The syntax is correct and that should work like this

Comment: No errors in my console - I have another element in my HTML which is updating just fine in the success block, so I'm pretty baffled about whats gone wrong, it definitely belongs to the same controller

Comment: Oh wait it should be `$scope.$apply()` with a `$` in the name of the function. But you should have had an error if you didn't put it yet as `$scope.apply` doesn't exist.

Comment: Had tried that too but still no luck - going to head to sleep and take another look in the morning, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Alright. I suspect your callback is in fact never called, otherwise you should have got an error for using `apply` instead of `$apply`, double check that tomorrow, good night

Comment: @floribon you were right the first time, I was getting an error as it was not a func (I had wrong dev console up).  Even after changing it to $scope.$apply(); I get the same results

Comment: What was the solution for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly why this made a difference but moving where `ng-controller` was defined solved my problem.

I removed ng-controller from the line:

```
<aside id="previousFeed" ng-controller="FetchUserCtrl">
```

And moved it to

```
<body ng-controller="FetchUserCtrl">
```

I don't see why this should make a difference, as from what I understand a child node will use the controller of its parent node, and in my case the parent node was `aside`

Any clarification on that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do like this.

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     $scope.requests.push( { name: data[i].name, dob: data[i].dob });
   }
});
```

or something like this

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
   var request = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     requests.push( { name: data[i].name, dob: data[i].dob });
   }

   $scope.$apply(function() {
     $scope.requests = request;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct.  You do not need to use the $scope.$apply call.  It is not needed.

I assume you know your html is incorrect.  It's need to be something like this:

```
<aside id="previousFeed" ng-controller="FetchUserCtrl">
    <div class="priorResult" ng-repeat="request in requests">
        <p>{{request.name - {{request.dob}}</p>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Again, remove the $scope.$apply call and check your html.  Outside of that post a plunker so we can see the problem in action.

Answer (score -1):

I think your code should work as you have written it.  If you could put just that part that's failing in plunker or jsfiddle, I bet a solution could be arrived at pretty quickly.  Also, the $scope.apply() should not be needed in a straight-forward situation like this.